# Why/how does 2>&1 change the order of output?

Tags: c, bash

I am playing around with stdin/stdout/stderr redirection and noticed something weird when using "2>&1"

I made a small program called "practice" for playing around with this that takes in a bunch of numbers from the user and then always prints a message to stderr at the end. So the output usually looks like this:

```
numbers....
this is stderr
```

However, after using the command "practice < input.txt > output 2>&1", I got this:

```
this is stderr
numbers....
```

Why did it print the last thing the program should print first? Also, if anyone can offer a more clear explanation on how 2>&1 works I would greatly appreciate it since what I have read does not really fully click with me. Thanks!

Comment: Please add a [mre] of the program to your question since that may be relevant to answering it.

Comment: `stderr` is not buffered, `stdout` is.

Comment: When stderr and stdout go to different places, there does not exist any guarantee of order of output between them. `2>&1` makes them go to the same place, so when you run it you have a guarantee.

Comment: That said, _by default_, stderr is unbuffered, whereas stdout is line-buffered when it goes to a TTY, or fully-buffered when it goes to a file. Fully-buffered content is allowed to build up in memory and flushed only occasionally to reduce performance overhead. None of this is bash behavior as such -- it's default behavior of the standard C library (and most non-C languages as well)

Comment: Consequently, for your purposes, it's not the `2>&1` that made the difference, it's the `>output`: That made the output be not to a TTY but instead to a file, so stdout changed from being line-buffered (written every time there's a newline) to fully-buffered (written every time enough content has built up, typically about 32kb or so), and thus delayed behind stderr.

Comment: See also [BashFAQ #9](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009).